# Stored procedure name tagging

Tags: stored-procedures, naming-conventions

Ever wonder what wikipedia's database schema looks like? I recently read this thread from [reddit](http://www.reddit.com/r/programming/comments/7r3mg/ever_wonder_what_the_wikipedia_database_schema/).

I like how their tables are tagged with a prefix so you can sort of tell its functionality, purpose, and relationship with other tables right off the bat.

One thing I do not notice is how they name their stored procedures. Do they even use SP?

I use MS SQL Server. Prefixing all stored procedures with USP_ or SP_ seems redundant and anti-beneficial as the object explorer already sorts it all out for me. How do you name your SPs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I like how their tables are tagged with a prefix so you can sort of tell its functionality, purpose, and relationship with other tables right off the bat

That is why you have Schemas in SQL Server, you create a schema to group several object together and then you can give the HR person just access to the HR schema

> Prefixing all stored procedures with USP_ or SP_ seems redundant and anti-beneficial as the object explorer already sorts it all out for me. How do you name your SPs?

SP_ should never be use because you will get a performance hit, whenever SQL server 'sees' a proc that starts with sp_ it will check the master database first, worst if MS decided to ship a proc with the sane name as yours and it starts with sp_ yours will never get executed

BTW not everyone is using the project explorer, some people like to do this in T-SQL

Answer (score 0):

I personally will prefix my stored procedures with a unique name the describes what it does.  For example.

SelectUserAccountById

or

InsertUserAccount

Typically the table name is referenced in the name, in the example above, the table would be UserAccount.

I do not prefix my stored procedures with SP or anything similar UNLESS I am building an extension that goes into a framework such as DotNetNuke, then I use a prefix for my company name.

Answer (score 0):

I find it useful to name the strored proc as
TableName_Action

example RefClient_Insert, RefClient_Search, RefEmployee_Delete

This way, since the tables are grouped (Ref = Reference in this case) the SPs are grouped too.

Note that I have used _ just for clarity, you may skip it if you like.

Answer (score 0):

I started naming all of the SQL objects with a ***widget type*** prefix. For example...

```
Photo Gallery Database Objects (abbreviated list)
Old Name          | New Name
-------------------------------------------------
tblCategories     | tblPGCategories
tblItems          | tblPGItems
spGetCategories   | spPGGetCategories
spUpdateCategory  | spPGUpdateCategory
spGetItems        | spPGGetItems
spUpdateItem      | spPGUpdateItems
```

```
Event Calendar Database Objects (abbreviated list)
Old Name          | New Name
-------------------------------------------------
tblCategories     | tblECCategories
tblItems          | tblECItems
spGetCategories   | spECGetCategories
spUpdateCategory  | spECUpdateCategory
spGetItems        | spECGetItems
spUpdateItem      | spECUpdateItems
```

We developed lots of websites and when a customer wanted a piece of functionalty we thought we could sell to others we would create it as a ***widget***. We would then market these widgets to other customers.
This worked great until we started adding widgets we developed from other websites. We wound up with ***duplicate names*** for some of our code. So, out of necessity we implement a ***widget type*** naming convention. This made it very easy to integrate all the widgets we created.